# Maven and Spring Boot: how to build a flat jar with reduced size (using proguard or similar)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, proguard

I'm working on a Maven Spring Boot Application (no web, only desktop). The project has just 30 classes, but the spring boot dependencies usage produce at the end a 13MByte jar. It's possible to use Proguard or any kind of plugin to integrate with Spring Boot to reduce JAR size? My project pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <url>https://github.com/xxx</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.boot.mainclass>oorg.example.Application</spring.boot.mainclass>

        <antlr.version>4.7.1</antlr.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>

        <proguard.maven.plugin.version>2.2.0</proguard.maven.plugin.version>
        <proguard.version>6.2.0</proguard.version>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${antlr.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <listener>true</listener>
                            <visitor>true</visitor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>${antlr.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>Example</finalName>
                            <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I try to integrate with a proguard plugin, but I can not find any way to make it works. Any ideas to accomplish this task?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${proguard.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>${proguard.version}</proguardVersion>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>suca${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
<!--                        <option>-shrink</option>-->
<!--                        <option>-optimize</option>-->
            <!-- This option will replace all strings in reflections method invocations with new class names.
                 For example, invokes Class.forName('className')-->
            <option>-adaptclassstrings</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original annotations and etc. Otherwise all we be removed from files.-->
            <option>-keepattributes
                Exceptions,
                InnerClasses,
                Signature,
                Deprecated,
                SourceFile,
                LineNumberTable,
                *Annotation*,
                EnclosingMethod
            </option>
            <!-- This option will save all original names in interfaces (without obfuscate).-->
            <option>-keepnames interface **</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original methods parameters in files defined in -keep sections,
                 otherwise all parameter names will be obfuscate.-->
            <option>-keepparameternames</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original class files (without obfuscate) but obfuscate all
                 in domain and service packages.-->
            <option>-keep
                class ${spring.boot.mainclass} {
                public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
                }
            </option>
            <!-- This option ignore warnings such as duplicate class definitions and classes in incorrectly
                named files-->
            <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original class files (without obfuscate) in service package-->
            <!--<option>-keep class com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.service { *; }</option>-->
            <!-- This option will save all original interfaces files (without obfuscate) in all packages.-->
            <option>-keep interface * extends * { *; }</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original defined annotations in all class in all packages.-->
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                }
            </option>
        </options>
        <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
        <libs>
            <!--Put here your libraries if required-->
            <!--<lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>-->
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>${proguard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Note: all dependency has almost a class that I use in my project, I can not remove them.

Comment: The first thing I would check do you really need guava? It is already 2.7 MiB in size? Furthermore have you checked all the deps which are in the resulting application?

Comment: Do you really use `spring-boot-starter-aop`? (ca. 2 MiB) so from 13 MiB down to 11 MiB; removing guava results in 8.1 MiB ...Guava has also some transitive dependencies etc.

Comment: Both libraries are used. That I need is to thrown away all the useless spring classes that my project does not use.

Comment: Maybe you should consider not to use spring ? The question is what your app really needs if you writing desktop app? What does that mean? If you don't use web what is used anyway?  And you wrote you need both libraries? Usually my experience is that by using plain java (in particular jdk8+)  it's often easier and you get rid of the dependencies cause I doubt that you use more than 10% of guava etc.  But the real question is: Is the effort really worth to reduce a 13 MiB size app ?

Comment: I prefer to use IOC pattern and I like to use the benefit that spring framework offer. It is one of de-facto standard in Java world to create an enterprise-level application. My project is a simple study, but I think solving this kind of problem can be useful in real application too.

Comment: You can use depclean (https://github.com/castor-software/depclean) to detect unnecessary dependencies. Then exclude them in your pom. This will minimize your bundled Jar significantly.